# MKMapView - annotations block each other when coordinates are close

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, maps

[image: Map]

I have a map with big pictures for annotations and when coordinates close to each other - one annotation is over another. Is there any methods to see them both entirely?

Comment: can u provide a screenshot of how you would like to see the annotations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better [solution](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tsclustermapview) !

Change
`@property (assign, nonatomic) CGSize clusterAnnotationViewSize` to set a size of your own annotation and it will do everything. Also this pod implements same thing, as mentioned [earlier](http://blog.stormid.com/2013/01/handling-annotation-pins-on-the-same-coordinate/).

Comment: my settings: _mapView.clusterAnnotationViewSize = CGSizeMake(77, 77); _mapView.clusterPreferredVisibleCount = 10; _mapView.clusterEdgeBufferSize = ADClusterBufferNone; _mapView.clusterDiscrimination = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You can do some annotation clustering and display one annotation for both coordinates. If you really want to see them both and do not need to be exact shift them a bit like done in here

[Handling MKMapView Annotation Pins on the Same Coordinate](http://blog.stormid.com/2013/01/handling-annotation-pins-on-the-same-coordinate/)

But if you do care about precision detect the distance between two annotations. You want the distance on the screen not on the map. If the distance is over some treshold, you can present with two rotated annotations one reaching to the left and one to the right side. More can be studied from stuff written on topic of annotation clustering. Search on stack there is a ton of it.